# Number of the binary strings that have the given number of occurrences

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics, counting

How many binary strings exists that have exactly five occurrences of "00", three of "10", three of "01" and three of "11" ?

I tried to solve it using induction, or simple counting methods, I also tried to prove that there only exists 1 such binary string but couldn't.

Comment: How does this question relate to programming?

Comment: This is off-topic here, but isn't on [mathematics.se]. If you decide to post there, make sure to first read their posting guidelines.

Comment: As said in the answer, there are 15 bits. If you go bit by bit, and look at the consecutive adjacent bits (the first 2 bits, then 2nd-3rd, then 3rd-4th, and so on) then you can actually draw a state graph of the adjacent numbers (states being 00, 01, 10, 11). Look at 01 and 10, because you have to switch states through them (e.g., from 01 you either get 10 or 11) you can tell a lot about the different types of solutions and how many of them are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there must be exactly 14 pairs of adjacent bits, a matching string needs to be 15 bits long.

There are only 32768 15-bit strings. Just test them all.